# I've heard that it isn't possible to encode product types and sum types in a simply typed lambda calculus, but it seems for me that it's false

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, propositional-logic

Of course, it isn't possible to construct them directly since we hasn't these type constructors, but only function constructor (arrow). But suppose there are 2 types $A$ and $B$, from which we need to create a product (or tuple) type $A*B$ and also sum type $A+B$.

Let's remember the algebra of types: functional type $A \rightarrow B$ is equivalent to exponentiation: $B^A$. Now we need to create some kind of composite type in which addition and multiplication can ultimately be replaced solely by exponents, so we encode the sum and the product.

$P^{A*B} = (P^B)^A \Leftrightarrow (A*B) \rightarrow P = A \rightarrow B \rightarrow P$ (functional constructor is right-associative)

and

$P^{P^{A+B}} = P^{P^A*P^B} = (P^{P^B})^{P^A} \Leftrightarrow ((A+B) \rightarrow P) \rightarrow P = ((A \rightarrow P)*(B \rightarrow P)) \rightarrow P = (A \rightarrow P) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow P) \rightarrow P$

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151240/why-is-there-no-product-type-in-simply-typed-lambda-calculus) answer, the last technique is called "virtual embedding" by continuation. At the same time, I also heard about some theorems about the non-existence of conjunction and disjunction in implicative propositional logic, but I don't understand why these "virtual" products and sums aren't counted. (According to the Curry-Howard isomorphism, everything demonstrated regarding type theory also works in implicative logic).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is a virtual embedding?

Answer (score 7):

A phrase like "it is not possible to encode product types in the simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus (without product types)" means: it is not true that for every type $A$ and type $B$, there exists some type $X$ such that $X$ is (isomorphic to) the product of $A$ and $B$. It does *not* mean that there exist no types that are isomorphic to a type involving a product (in a calculus having product types).

For instance, you are correct that, for all types $A, B, P$ in the simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus with products, we have that $P^{A \times B}$ is isomorphic to $(P^B)^A$, so that we can encode the former type with the latter type when we do not have products. But we cannot construct a type isomorphic to $A \times B$ alone.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Church encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding), which are encodings of type constructions and datatypes in the [*polymorphic* $\lambda$-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F). That is, apart from having function types $\to$ we also need $\forall$ to quantify over all types.

For example, let us take your observation that $$((A + B) \to P) \to P) = (A \to B) \to (B \to P) \to P.$$ If we keep $P$ fixed then this is not very useful, but if we make sure that $P$ is arbitrary then it works:
$$A + B = \forall P .\, (A \to B) \to (B \to P) \to P.$$
The other observation of your works also to give
$$A \times B = \forall P .\, A \to B \to P.$$
And here are the natural numbers:
$$\mathbb{N} = \forall P .\, (P \to P) \to (P \to P),$$
The unit type is $1 = \forall P .\, P \to P$, the empty type is $0 = \forall P.\, P$, and so on.

This is just the basic idea. The topic has been studied by many people and there are lots of things to learn here. The Wikipedia links are a decent starting point.